# Scheduler processes with signals SIGTSTP and SIGCONT on linux

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Write a scheduler Round-Robin with the following characteristics:
The scheduler must accept quantum `qt` time and the processes to be performed as parameters on the command line with the following format:

```
./scheduler qt path_process1 startTime1 executionTime1 path_process2 startTime2 executionTime2 ...
```

Each of the processes that create and will rotate the scheduler should be a separate program that prints a message every 0.5s in the following format:

```
Program i: Messages printed: 1.
Program i: Messages printed: 2. 
Program i: Messages ...
    ...
```

When cyclic initiation and termination of each process itself will print messages:

```
Process pid is executing.
//Execution of process pid
Process pid is suspended.
```

Stopping and execution processes will be with signals `SIGTSTP` and `SIGCONT` .
 Consider and comment system behavior for small and large values ​​of the quantum time (e.g. qt = 0.5s, 1s, 2s, 4s) for five processes with the following starting and running times.

```
startTimes = [0,2,4,6,8]
execTimes = [3,6,4,5,2]
```

Given Hint:
 To carry out a process child as a separate program, use the command `execl (...)`.
 For measuring the time elapsed from the start of operation of the scheduler, use the command `gettimeofday (...)`.

## Code

### Scheduler.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>

using namespace std;

float qt;
int k,j,i;
int total_time=0;
int pass_time=0;

void stp_handler(int signal){
}
void con_handler(int signal){
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int p=2;
     int s=3;
     int e=4;
     int count=0;

     signal(SIGTSTP,stp_handler);
     signal(SIGCONT,con_handler);
     int start_time[(argc-2)/3];
     float execution_time[(argc-2)/3];
     char *path_process[(argc-2)/3];
     float remaining_time[(argc-2)/3];
     timeval time;
     int start,end;


     if (argc < 2)
        {
        cout<<"You didn't enter any arguments" << endl;
        exit(0);
        }
    else{
        qt = atoi(argv[1]);
        while (count < ((argc-2)/3) ){
            path_process[count] = argv[p];
            start_time[count] = atoi(argv[s]);
            execution_time[count] = atoi(argv[e]);
            remaining_time[count] = execution_time[count];
            total_time = total_time + execution_time[count];
            cout << path_process[count] << " " << start_time[count] << " " << execution_time[count] << endl;
            p+=3;
            s+=3;
            e+=3;
            count++;
        }
    }
        i=0;
        pid_t pid[count];

    while(i<count){
         pid_t par,child;
         child=fork();

         if (child==0){
            par = getppid();
            cout << "Child pid: " << i << " " << getpid() << endl << "Parent pid: " << par << endl;
            char num[100]={0x0};
            sprintf(num,"%d",i+1);
            char pi[100]={0x0};
            sprintf(pi,"%d",getpid());
            execl(path_process[i],path_process[i],pi,num,(char*)0);
            exit(0);
         }

         else{
            sleep(1);
            pid[i] = child;
            i++;
         }
    }

    i=0;
    cout << endl << "Processes time: " << total_time << endl << endl;
    gettimeofday(&time,NULL);
    start = time.tv_sec;

    while(pass_time<total_time){
        for(j=0;j<count;j++){
            if (pass_time<start_time[j]){
                continue;
            }
            else if (remaining_time[j]<=0){
                continue;
            }
            else if (remaining_time[j]>= qt){
                kill(pid[j],SIGCONT);
                usleep(qt*1000000);
                kill(pid[j],SIGTSTP);
                pass_time = pass_time + qt;
                remaining_time[j]=remaining_time[j]-qt;
                i++;
            }
            else{
                kill(pid[j],SIGCONT);
                usleep(remaining_time[j]*1000000);
                kill(pid[j],SIGTSTP);
                pass_time = pass_time + remaining_time[j];
                remaining_time[j]=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    sleep(1);
    gettimeofday(&time,NULL);
    end = time.tv_sec;
    cout << "Scheduler time: " << end - start << endl;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        kill(pid[i],SIGKILL);

    return 0;
}
```

### Signals.cpp

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>

using namespace std;

int j=1;
char* pid;

void sig_handler(int signal){

    if (signal == SIGCONT){
    cout << endl << "Process " << pid << " is executing." << endl << endl;
    j=0;
    }
    else if (signal == SIGTSTP){
    cout << endl << "Process " << pid << " is suspended." << endl << endl;
    j=1;
    }
}

  main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {

     signal(SIGTSTP,sig_handler);
     signal(SIGCONT,sig_handler);
     pid = argv[1];
     int i=1;

     while(1){
        while(j==0){
            cout << "Program: " << argv[2] << " messages printed: " << i << endl;
            usleep(500000);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

## Output from Scheduler

(This is correct I guess)

> ```
> process1 0 3
> process2 2 6
> process2 4 4
> process3 6 5
> process4 8 2
> Child pid: 0 3406
> Parent pid: 3405
> Child pid: 1 3407
> Parent pid: 3405
> Child pid: 2 3408
> Parent pid: 3405
> Child pid: 3 3409
> Parent pid: 3405
> Child pid: 4 3410
> Parent pid: 3405
>
> Processes time: 20
> ```

## Output from Signals

I get nothing but as I mentioned above I expect it to be somehow like this.

> ```
> Program i: Messages printed: 1.
> Program i: Messages printed: 2. 
> Program i: Messages ...
>     ...
> ```

When cyclic initiation and termination of each process itself will print messages:

> ```
> Process pid is executing.
> //Execution of process pid
> Process pid is suspended.
> ```

P.S: In order to get the scheduler to work I compile it and run it with

```
>./scheduler 0.5 process1 0 3 process2 2 6 process2 4 4 process3 6 5 process4 8 2
```

Why don't the signals cause any output?

Comment: "Why don't the signals cause any output?" Because signals don't generate output. Signal *handlers* might, but in general shouldn't, as most of the output-generating functions are not re-entrant, and thus are not safe, unless you want to resort to `write()` or `send()`...

Comment: I compiled this, and see plenty of output. I'm using the command line `./scheduler 0.5 Signals 0 3 Signals 2 6 Signals 4 4`. If you're using a command line that contains `process1`, `process2`, etc., do you have an executable files named `process1` and `process2` in the current directory? That's what `execl` is going to try to run.